# Calculo de porcentagem com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou montando uma função para fazer o calculo usando porcentagem.
No meu teste online funciona.

http://jsfiddle.net/pfrk0v0s/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        valorTotaldaNota    = "1.000,00";
        valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(",", "");
        adValorem           = "0.33";
        gris                = "0.20";

        v1 = valorTotaldaNota * adValorem / 100;
        v2 = valorTotaldaNota * gris / 100;


        alert(  v1 + v2 );


});
```

Mas em meu arquivo local, o calculo não fica correto e aparece um monte de zero na frete. Ex: **0.0087**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".seguro").click(function() {

            valorTotaldaNota    = $("#valorTotaldaNota").val();
            valorTotaldaNota    = (valorTotaldaNota.replace(",", ""));
            adValorem           = ($("#adValorem").val());
            gris                = <?php echo $gris; ?>

            v1 = valorTotaldaNota * adValorem / 100;
            v2 = valorTotaldaNota * gris / 100;

            $("#valordoSeguro").val( v1 + v2 );

    }); 
});
```

Comment: Tiago juntei uma resposta com uma explicação mais elaborada. Espero que seja útil.

Answer (score 3):

Quando tens uma string `'1.000,00'` e fazes `'1.000,00'.replace(",", "");` isso vai dar

```
'1.00000' // tipo string
```

Por sorte, em JavaScript, `'1.00000' * 5` dá 5. Apesar de `1.00000` ser uma string e não um numero. O JavaScript não usa a virgula, usa somente o ponto para dividir a parte decimal. Aí `'1.00000'` é na verdade lido como 1.

#### Como fazer então?

Para fazer operações de aritmética tens de estar a trabalhar com numeros e não com strings. Podes usar uma função para limpar a entrada e retornar um numero. Ela tem de conseguir tratar ambos os casos onde a virgula divide a parte decimal como `1.000,00` mas também os outros valores que colocaste como `"0.33"`...

```
function conversor(str){
    if (typeof str == 'number') return str;
    var nr;
    var virgulaSeparaDecimais = str.match(/(,)\d{2}$/);
    if (virgulaSeparaDecimais) nr = str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')
    else nr = str.replace(',', '');
    return parseFloat(nr);
}
```

Uma sugestão de código seria:

```
function conversor(str) {
    if (typeof str == 'number') return str;
    var nr;
    var virgulaSeparaDecimais = str.match(/(,)\d{2}$/);
    if (virgulaSeparaDecimais) nr = str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')
    else nr = str.replace(',', '');
    return parseFloat(nr);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".seguro").click(function () {
        var valorTotaldaNota = conversor($("#valorTotaldaNota").val());
        var adValorem = conversor($("#adValorem").val());
        var gris = conversor( <? php echo $gris; ?> )

        var v1 = valorTotaldaNota * adValorem / 100;
        var v2 = valorTotaldaNota * gris / 100;

        $("#valordoSeguro").val(v1 + v2);
    });
});
```

Repara que estavas a omitir `var` na declaração de variáveis. Evita isso pois estás a exportar para o espaço global e podes re-escrever outas variáveis sem querer.

A regex `(,)\d{2}$` procura uma virgula `(,)` seguida por 2 digitos `\d{2}` que estejam no final da *string* `$`. Se os teus numeros tiverem parte decimal variante a coisa fica mais complexa. Nesse caso diz para eu corrigir aqui.

Comment: esse conversor da erro quando usa 1.000.000,00  só tira o primeiro ponto(.)

Comment: @JuniorRamoty tens razão! Corrigi, obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o problema.
Faltava mais uma conversão.

```
valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(".", "");
valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(",", ".");
```

Primeiro, tira o ponto e depois no lugar da virgula coloca o ponto.

Agora deu certo.